# adMod with phonegap cloud build

Tags: javascript, android, html, admob, phonegap-build

I have an `HTML5`&`JavaScript` application that I am building using `PhoneGap`'s cloud build. I can't find a way to implement `adMob` into the app without using `Java` in some way.

I built the app using `notpadd++`, and and the `PhoneGap` `cloud` with `github` and i don't have a single line of `Java`. My research showed me that using `AdSense` on a mobile application is not allowed, so I'm in a bit of a pickle...

I'm on `PhoneGap` version `3.1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugins that you can find through the docs at Phonegap Build but at present there is not an easy way to do this.

This is one of the things that many users have been asking for (including me). Please go to the PGB support community and add your voice to those who want this.